# Get an Average of a row with dynamic columns in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to get the average of a row in google sheets with dynamic columns?

for example i have the following data

in cell A2 im using the formula

```
=AVG(B2:AA2)
```

but it returns as #NAME?

i know it works if its just

```
=AVG(B2:D2)
```

but i need the columns to be dynamic

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `=AVG(B2:D2)`
**In Google sheets there is no such function.**
That is the reason you see the error `#NAME?`

Instead you have to use

```
=AVERAGE(B2:AA2)
```